# Convert a directory into a mysql database

Tags: mysql, mariadb

(I use MariaDB, in case this helps)
Hey guys, I recently had problems with my hosting provider and I backed up my files, well, they just gave me the raw files and I didn't even have choice to dump the mysql databases, so I just have the /var/lib/mysql and I don't know what to do with it. I don't know if I can dump it so that it converts to a database or how... I asked for help with my provider, looked up for problems like mine but can't find anything related, so I had to ask for help here.

Comment: Start a MariaDB instance, hope you know the version as the minimum version, with all those files in /var/lib/mysql. You can also include this directory in starting a mariadb volume `-v ./localfiles:/var/lib/mysql:z`

Comment: Install precisely the same MariaDB version into precisely the same folder. Stop the server. Replace the whole datadir with saved one. Start server. Try to access the data.

Comment: Comments should only be used for asking for clarification, or to leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post, or to add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated), or to provide site usage guidance.  See the [help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for details.